# Why does intellij IDEA highlight build.sbt?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I've recently create a new project with sbt in IDEA and got this

[image]

What's wrong with it? I have scala plugin installed and enabled and IDEA version is 14.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution to resolve this problem. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767860/3974509

You need to invalidate cahce and dsable old SBT plugin.
Caches invalidation: File > Invalidate Caches/Restatr