# Scala: IntelliJ highlights correct code in red

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-plugin

One fine day `IntelliJ` started highlighting my working `Scala` code in red. While following commands run without a hitch, `IntelliJ` thinks that code is full of errors an missing a lot of `dependencies`.

- `sbt clean`
- `sbt reload`
- `sbt update`
- `sbt compile`
- `sbt assembly`

It reports a lot of `Cannot resolve symbols` in `imports`, `classes` and method-calls on `objects` like the following. Moreover, it thinks a lot of imports are unused (for the symbols that it can't find)
[image]

Interestingly, all this is happening in only one of my projects (that contains two `submodules` inside parent module), while other `Scala` projects (including those containing `submodules`) are working fine.

Things that I've tried without luck:

- Delete (`rm -rf`) build-related directories like `.idea`, `target`, `~/.ivy2/caches`
- `Invalidate Caches / Restart...`
- Update `IntelliJ IDEA` and `Scala` plugin to latest versions
- Close and re-import the project, quit `IntelliJ`, reboot the PC (!)

---

I'm using:

- **IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.2 (Community Edition)**
- **Build #IC-173.4127.27, built on December 25, 2017**
- **JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b8 x86_64**
- **JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o**
- **Mac OS X 10.13.2**

My project configurations are:

- **Scala v2.11.11**
- **SBT v1.0.3**

---

Once again, I'd like to remind that my `Scala` code is completely functional and that I'm able to run the `JAR` generated by `sbt assembly` elsewhere without an issue.

Comment: I would suggest to raise this question with JetBrains support directly, IntelliJ well known for these kind of issues.

Comment: Are you able to provide a project or steps that reproduce the issue? Ideally report them on https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL

Comment: Here's the [link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205997079/comments/360000001364) to the related issue on `JetBrains` Forums (`YouTrack`)

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me: [Why does intellij IDEA highlight build.sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950492/why-does-intellij-idea-highlight-build-sbt)

Go to the menu: File > Invalidate Caches/Restart

Answer (score 0):

Such things happen when project SDK is not set. Also make sure that you have **Add Framework Support** -> **Scala** enabled.

Comment: But the list of frameworks does not include Scala. Please read the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13723282/3679900) by @sourcedelica