# Why intellij import project from SBT failed

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea 14 Ultimate.

I have a multimodule project with a `project/Build.scala`. Here is the layout of my project.

`- myproject
  - module 1
  - module 2
  - project
    - Build.scala`

I try to use the native SBT from scala plugin. I choose Import project from external model and then select SBT. Then I select the root folder of my project and click on Finish.

But the project is not well imported. Libraries are downloaded but all imports are in red in submodules (cannot resolve).

So I have to use sbt gen-idea, that works fine, but I would be very happy to get rid of it …

Comment: I think the latest IntelliJ Scala plug-in still has multiple issues with sbt import. One important thing is to let the background tasks complete. They take a while to index the dependencies, during that phase you see a lot of red. Also if you have pre-existing `.idea` files, I recommend wiping them and importing the project from scratch. In some cases switching the JDK version forward and backward helped. Probably caching problems. I think a new plug-in version will be published soon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem (IDEA 14 Ultimate). This solve that after import. 
File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... 
[Shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767463/intellij-14-create-import-a-scala-sbt-project)

Comment: This does not help. :/